# display age from date of birth?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi i have a site with users displayed on the front page. When users sign up to the site they sign up with their date of birth. This is stored in my database.

I have pulled the users from the database and have their location and name displaying.

I am also trying to add their age which is calculated from their date of birth. But at the moment it won't work, the users age isn't being displayed.

Can anyone help me find where i'm going wrong?

Code:

```
 <?php
 $dob = $platinum['dob'];

function age_from_dob($dob) {

    list($y,$m,$d) = explode('-', $dob);

    if (($m = (date('m') - $m)) < 0) {
        $y++;
    } elseif ($m == 0 && date('d') - $d < 0) {
        $y++;
    }

    return date('Y') - $y;

}

$dob = age_from_dob($dob);

?>

<?

        $platinum_set = get_platinum_users();
        while ($platinum = mysql_fetch_array($platinum_set)) {
            echo"
            <div class=\"platinumcase\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$platinum['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$platinum['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><h58> {$platinum['first_name']} {$platinum['last_name']}</h58><br/><br/><h52>{$platinum['$dob']}<br/><br/>{$platinum['location']}</h52>

            </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an echo when instead you should have another set of ?><?php blocks...

Comment: You're assigning $m in the first if statement, which is likely unintentional. Switch it to two equals signs instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function age_from_dob($dob) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$dob, $tz)->diff(new DateTime('now', $tz))->y;
}
```

Comment: While example code is helpful, this answer is not.  You have failed to explain what this code does, how it works, or how it will help.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know which templating engine you use and what is allowd and what not... but normally the easiest way is the best ... so try this

```
<?php
 $dob = $platinum['dob'];

function age_from_dob($dob) {

       $dob = '1999-12-03'; 
       $age = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('now'))->y;  
       return $age;
}

?>

<?

        $platinum_set = get_platinum_users();
        while ($platinum = mysql_fetch_array($platinum_set)) {
        $age = age_from_dob($platinum['dob']);
             echo "
            <div class=\"platinumcase\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$platinum['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$platinum['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><h58> {$platinum['first_name']} {$platinum['last_name']}</h58><br/><br/><h52> ".$age." <br/><br/>{$platinum['location']}</h52>

            </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: how would i add that into the div so that it's displayed for each individual platinum user?

Comment: sorry... actually i didnt test it.. just make sure that you use the result of age_from_dob($platinum['dob']) correctly in your output... another possible way would be this last edit

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to return age of my user. Hope this helps

```
function HowOld($DOB)
    {
            if($DOB)
                    {
                $birthday = strtotime($DOB);
                $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d "));
                $difference = $date - $birthday;
                $years = $difference/(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
                $value = floor($years);
                return $value;
            }
        return false;
    }
```